# How to fetch folder contents along with other custom types?

Tags: alfresco

I am new to alfresco. This is the custom model. I need to fetch folder contents (cm:folder) along with other custom types (sparepart, metal). The following method is used to fetch the types but the folder contents are not being returned. What changes need to be made in the custom-model xml file (and in the java class) for it to work properly?

For example Factory is the parent container.under Factory ,emp:metal,emp:asset and emp:sparepart are sub containers.so when i add these subcontainers under Factory containers then all these associations will come.like wise i need to another association called folder association.i can also create folders and contents inside Factory Container.existing model is working fine.but how to add emp:folder type as association inside Factory Container.when i click   view node browser its not showing type as "emp:folder" and also target associations.

```
List<AssociationRef> associationRefs = nodeService.getTargetAssocs(nodeRef,
                EMPContentModel.EMP_NAMESPACE_URI_QNAME_PATTERN);
```

if i add another association under emp:fac then also its not working..

```
  <association name="emp:containsFactoryFolder">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>cm:folder</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
```

custommodel.xml

```
    <namespaces>
            <namespace uri="http://www.emp.com/model/emp-cms-core/2.0" prefix="emp"/>

        </namespaces>


        <types>
            <type name="emp:container">
                <title>Container</title>
                <parent>cm:folder</parent>
            </type>

            <type name="emp:fac">
                <title>Factory</title>
                <parent>emp:container</parent>

                <associations>
                    <association name="emp:containsFactoryAsset">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:asset</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                    <association name="emp:containsFactorySparePart">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:sparepart</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                    <association name="emp:containsFactoryMetal">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:metal</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                </associations>
             </type>

            <type name="emp:sparepart">
                <title>Spare Part</title>
                <parent>emp:container</parent>
                <properties>
                    <property name="emp:sparePartNumber">
                        <title>Spare Part Number</title>
                        <type>d:text</type>
                   </property>
               </properties>

                <associations>
                    <association name="emp:containsSparePartAsset">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:asset</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                    <association name="emp:containsSparePartMetal">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:metal</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                    <association name="emp:derivesFromSparePart">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>false</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:sparepart</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                </associations>
             </type>
            <type name="emp:metal">
                <title>Metal</title>
                <parent>emp:container</parent>

                <associations>
                    <association name="emp:containsMetalAsset">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:asset</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                    <association name="emp:derivesFromMetal">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>false</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:metal</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                    <association name="emp:containsMetalMetal">
                        <source>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </source>
                        <target>
                            <class>emp:metal</class>
                            <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                            <many>true</many>
                        </target>
                    </association>
                </associations>
            </type>

            <type name="emp:content">
                <title>Content</title>
                <parent>cm:content</parent>
            </type>
            <type name="emp:asset">
                <title>Asset</title>
                <parent>emp:content</parent>
           </type>

        </types>

    </model>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell me ,what you are expecting  nodeService.getTargetAssocs method to do ?

Comment: We cannot tell what your nodeRef is an instance of. I assume maybe it is a folder. You are then trying to get the target associations from that folder, and you are providing a QNAME, but because it is a constant and you have not provided the value, we also cannot tell what you think might be coming back. Also, if you can post your folder/object structure that would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need add configuration to your **share-config-custom.xml** add Documentlibrary configuration which will enable you to see your custom content type on user interface.

```
<types>
        <type name="cm:content">
        </type>

        <type name="cm:folder">
            <subtype name="emp:fac" />
            <subtype name="emp:sparepart" />
        </type>

        <type name="trx:transferTarget">
            <subtype name="trx:fileTransferTarget" />
        </type>

    </types>
```

Once you have those visible you can create normal folder and change it's type to your custom content type i.e(emp:fac etc...).

In order to add associate those folders with others you need to again add configuration related to folder properties in **share-config-custom.xml**

```
<config evaluator="model-type" condition="emp:fac">
        <forms>
            <form>
                <field-visibility>
                    <show id="cm:name" />
                    <show id="emp:containsFactoryAsset" />
                    <show id="emp:containsFactorySparePart" />

                    <show id="cm:title" force="true" />
                    <show id="cm:description" force="true" />
                </field-visibility>
            </form>
        </forms>
    </config>
```

Something like this.